# How to populate the list of all countries into select multiple and then determine which ones were selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular app I have a task of presenting to the user a "select multiple" list of ALL countries, and, after they make their multiple selections, to be able to determine which countries were selected.

I understand how to use ng-repeat inside of the  tag, but, I don't know how to properly populate my $scope.countries model array in my controller. ( my only guess is to have the entire country list in a database, and then use ng-init to push all records onto the $scope.countries array, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this)
My second challenge is to be able to iterate over the select object, after one or more items were selected, and determine which once were selected.
Currently, my select looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="selectbasic">What country is the data for</label>
                        <div>
                            <select type="text" class="form-control multiselect multiselect-icon" multiple="multiple"  ng-model="SelectedCountries">
                                <option ng-repeat="country in countries">
                                {{country.name}}
                                </option> 
                            </select> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
$scope.countries = [
        {
            name: "US"
        },
        {
            name: "UK"
        },
        {
            name: "France"
        }
];
```

Comment: Here's a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473096/angularjs-select-multiple-options-from-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tarris/6S2Nk/

Here's the gist of it:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="con">
    <div ng-repeat="item in countries">
        <input type='checkbox' ng-model="item.checked" />{{item.name}}
    </div>
    <button ng-click="checkit()">Check it</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('con', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.countries = [
    {id:'us', name: 'United States', checked: false},
    {id:'fr', name: 'France', checked: false},
    {id:'sw', name: 'Sweden', checked: true}
  ];
  $scope.checkit = function(){
    var list = [];
    for(var p in $scope.countries){
        if($scope.countries[p].checked){
            list.push($scope.countries[p].name);
        }
    }
    alert(list);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: This is pretty good! Do you know of any way to wrap this checkbox list into some scrollable container? Since I have to present the list of ALL countries, I don't want it to take up entire page all by itself.  -Eugene

Comment: I just updated the fiddle.  The checkboxes are in a scrollable container and there's also a regular `<select>` option.