# Angular JS: Pushing objects into an array. It is creating an object, then another array. I need it to create separate objects. Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, push

After adding "multiple = true" to my select, it's adding an array of objects to the model instead of each object separately.

This is what I want:

```
{
    teams: [
      {name: 'team1'},
      {name: 'team2'},
      {name: 'team3'}
    ]
}
```

But instead I'm getting

```
{
    teams: [
      {name: 'team1'},
      {name: ['team2','team3']}
    ]
}
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ILxWhpX.png]

Pic of data structure issue.

2 Teams put in manually are objects. Teams put in using md-select are an array within an object.

```
$scope.baseGitblituser = {
    CODE HERE DELETED FOR READABILITY, WAS FOR OTHER USER FIELDS
    teams:
      [{name: "xignorex All Users"},
      {name: "Test Users"}]
};
```

This initiates the scope for the user and adds the global teams manually that all users will contain.

```
// this is created elsewhere using $scope.gitblitUser = angular.copy($scope.baseGitblituser);
$scope.gitblitUser.teams.push({name:user.team});
```

This is part of the function that is called when the md-select button is clicked to create a new user. This is how the teams array is updated with new teams.

```
  <md-select ng-model="user.team" multiple="true" name="teams" placeholder="your default team " style="min-width: 200px;">
         <md-optgroup label="">
               <md-option ng-value="team.name" ng-repeat="team in teams">{{team.name}}</md-option>
                            </md-optgroup>
```

This is the HTML portion.

Comment: Too many words, not enough code. Maybe i missed something in the text, but, i don't quite understand what exactly the problem here is. None of the code you have provided recreates what you mention in your title.

Comment: typo? `$scope.baseGitblituser` not the same as `$scope.gitblitUser`? or how does one become the other?

Comment: $scope.baseGitblituser is the scope that is preset for all users. I then use 
    $scope.gitblitUser = angular.copy($scope.baseGitblituser);

To copy that scope into the new one. I will edit that in my main post, thank you.

Comment: Gotcha. So when you select multiple, it's adding multiple, to a single team, rather than to the overall team array, right?

Comment: Basically, if you refer to the first picture.. is there a way to make md-select push in separate objects rather than an array in a nested object?

Comment: "Gotcha. So when you select multiple, it's adding multiple, to a single team, rather than to the overall team array, right?" - Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Not sure. But, a workaround would be to use a separate model that is a copy of the one you want to update, and an ng-change that takes objects from the copy model and moves them to the one you want to update.

Comment: I'm sorry to have to ask you, but could you go more in detail about how to do that? Again I'm fairly newer to this stuff.

Comment: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" 
Should we do that if you don't mind?

Comment: Just kidding.. not enough reputation for chat.

Comment: do you mind if i rewrite the text portion of your question to demonstrate how this question could be made clearer?

Comment: I don't mind at all.

Comment: Thanks Kevin... that does seem a lot more clear, concise, and to the point. I appreciate it.

Comment: This might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473096/angularjs-select-multiple-options-from-object i'm not too familiar with this so i'm not sure. It's not exactly the same, but it describes a similar problem, and shows the ng-change event that you would need to fix it.

Comment: I'll be back to check that link in about 5 minutes or so. Again, thank you so much for your help with this.

Comment: Alright, looked over the link. Seems like it could fix my issue. Since I'm a noobie, this may take a while. I'll report back on how it goes - thanks again.

Comment: So the link that you referred me to might've worked... but it got a little interesting for me and changed up my html a lot. BUT! I saw the for loop in there... and even though it's used differently, it gave me the idea to try messing with a for loop to pull objects out of the array individually.

`$scope.gitblitUser.teams.push({name:user.team});`

Changed to -


`for (var i=0; i < user.team.length; i++){

            $scope.gitblitUser.teams.push({name: user.team[i]});

          }`

So ultimately... your link helped spark the for loop thought - so thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

So the link that Kevin B referred me to might've worked... but it got a little interesting for me and changed up my html a lot. BUT! I saw the for loop in there... and even though it's used differently, it gave me the idea to try messing with a for loop to pull objects out of the array individually.

```
$scope.gitblitUser.teams.push({name:user.team});
```

Changed to -

```
for (var i=0; i < user.team.length; i++){ $scope.gitblitUser.teams.push({name: user.team[i]}); }
```

So ultimately... your link helped spark the for loop thought - so thank you very much!

Thought I'd post this here incase anyone runs into the issue I did in the future.