# select tag does not support multiple

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, multiple-select

In my code I use ng-options to bind data to select tag,also I set the multiple property to true.

```
<select ng-if="exp.metaData.elementType =='in'"
multiple=""
ng-multiple="true" 
class="form-control"
ng-model="exp.value"
ng-options="value.id as value.title for value in exp.dataSource">
   <option value=""> Select ...</option>
</select>
```

But in run time in browser, the select tag does not support multiple,also I do not see  `multiple="" or`  `ng-multiple="true"` when I Inspect the select element.  (f12->Elements)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs select multiple options from object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473096/angularjs-select-multiple-options-from-object)

Comment: Are you sure about your condition?  Maybe you have multiple select tags and what you have seen in browser is another select tag. Also you don't need multiple="" and ng-multiple both.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the minimal setup example for multiple select in angular.
Not sure why you would need a `Please select` option in multiple select, though.

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.options = [
    {name: 'aaa', value: '1'},
    {name: 'bbb', value: '2'},
    {name: 'ccc', value: '3'}
  ];
  
  vm.selected = [];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test as test'>
  <select multiple ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in test.options" ng-model="test.selected">
  </select>
  
  <div>{{test.selected}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean I should initialize the ng-model value as array in controller? Although I have already done the hint you told me. But it still does not work.

Comment: No dear Armita, It would treat this field like an array when binds to your multiple select model.