# Multiple select with track by behaving differently in angular to 1.4.x

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

I have updated my product **from Angular 1.2.x to 1.4.x** .

After updating the angularjs to 1.4.x; here i am facing issue

**What I have**:
I have added snippet with angular 1.2.0 AND here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/c69mtexu/) with 1.4.8 with same code.

**Explanation** :

Select any one user from multi-select box, make it Active.
Select second user (using ctrl key).

**Observation**:
 1.2.x  : First selected value is still active (true)
 1.4.x  : After selecting second value first value active flag get reset.

Why this happening ?
What should I do to get the existing (1.2.x)output in 1.4.x

Note: My English writing is not too good. please avoid the grammatical mistake or correct it :)

Thanks!

```js
var app = angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('selectIssue',function($scope){
 $scope.users = [{
   name:"Rohit",
    active:false
  },
  {
   name:"Virat",
    active:false
  },
  {
   name:"Viky",
    active:false
  }];
  $scope.selectedName = [];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="selectIssue">
  <div>
   <select multiple ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="user.name for user in users track by user.name"></select>
  </div>
    Selected value table :
    <div>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>isActive</td>
          <td>Output</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="n in selectedName">
          <td>{{n.name}}</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="n.active"></td>
          <td>{{n}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "What should I do to get the existing (2.1.x)output in 2.4.x" Wait, we taking 1.X aka AngularJs or 2.X aka Angular or Angular 2?

Comment: You'll have to put an ng-change on the select, then use that to push the values into the model. See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473096/angularjs-select-multiple-options-from-object

Comment: @DanteTheSmith updated the Question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes @rrd . I have this option as well, ng-change in multiple select it headache. this is not return the current selected value even not return the $event. Every time I need to refactor all the selected value with previous  updated once  (I have maintain the one more  object array for the this to maintain the active users

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating $scope.names when you change the checkbox, but $scope.selectedNames.
Which mean you have to use ng-change on the checkbox to update $scope.names aswell.

```
$scope.updateName = function(name) {
    angular.forEach($scope.names, function(n) {
        if (n.name === name.name) {
            n.active = name.active
        }
    })
}
```

This is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c69mtexu/1/)

Comment: This is true. But why it worked in 1.2 still confuses me :)

Comment: Why should I update my ng-options? I am updating the ng-model (selected values), it's not a issue if I have remove the active user from the list and after adding once again it's not active. I have concern about the user is in list have not touch them and after added another one in to the list; the existing users are get reset

Comment: @DanteTheSmith same confusion here?

Comment: You can't get both @Sachink, or you'd have to use an ng-change on the select aswell in which whenever you remove one selectedName, you set the active to false aswell.

Comment: And by the way you wanted to get the exact same output with 1.4, which I just gave you, so I don't really understand what's the problem here. :) I'm just doing what 1.2 angular binding used to do, and isn't supported anymore in 1.4 i guess.